# How to use XtraDB and TokuDB in Percona?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, percona, tokudb, xtradb

After trying several times, I finally installed Percona on my Macbook using Homebrew and successfully connected to it via MySQL Workbench, but when I want to create XtraDB tables:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `TestSchema`.`TestTable` (
  `ID` BIGINT(0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = XtraDB;

ERROR 1286: Unknown storage engine 'XtraDB'
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `TestSchema`.`TestTable` (
  `ID` BIGINT(0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = XtraDB
```

Same error with TokuDB too.

I have read that Percona supports both XtraDB and TokuDB as well as InnoDB.
Should I activate theme somewhere?!

Comment: Install MariaDB; you get TokuDB with it.  Don't worry about XtraDB vs InnoDB, the differences have somewhat been merged.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you Rick.

Comment: I don't like homebrew at all! Just use the official Percona guide `https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/installation/apt_repo.html` As far as I know TokuDB is not available in homebrew at all! Just use the best (official) documentation for install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within Percona Server, XtraDB *is* InnoDB. In other words, 'CREATE TABLE ... ENGINE=INNODB' will create you an XtraDB table.

TokuDB is not at all supported on homebrew/Mac/OS/X in any way and likely will not even compile.

In a regular distro of Percona Server 5.6/5.7, you need to follow these directions for the proper pre-requisites and the procedure for enabling the storage engine : https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/tokudb/tokudb_installation.html

--
George O. Lorch III
Software Engineer, Percona

Comment: Thank you George. Is it possible to install XtraDB/TokuDB on a regular MySQL installation so we can have all engines in a single place? If yes, is there any advantage to use Percona instead of MySQL?

Comment: Yes, you can easily install Percona Server with XtraDB and TokuDB on almost any modern linux distribution.

Comment: The decision to use Oracle MySQL vs Percona Server vs MariaDB is a personal one, each has benefits and it entirely depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank you George for your time. Sorry but I didn't asked my question properly. You said that TukoDB is available as a plugin for Percona Server. I wanna know that can I install TukoDB and XtraDB plugins on MySQL, so I can have a single MySQL installation with Percona Server and MariaDB table engines? If yes, Is there any advantage on installing Percona Server instead of XtraDB plugin on MySQL? (performance/more concurrent operations/consistency/etc).

Comment: Oracle MySQL Server, Percona Server, and MariaDB are different servers, or variants of the MySQL server. Percona Server comes with its own version of InnoDB called XtraDB that is identical in all user facing functions as InnoDB but with some feature and performance enhancements and bug fixes.  Percona Server also comes packaged with an optional TokuDB storage engine that you may enable and use alongside InnoDB if you have a valid reason to.  MariaDB also Packages a branch/fork/copy of both XtraDB and TokuDB.  XtraDB and TokuDB are NOT available for the standard Oracle MySQL distribution.

Comment: A decent read on history and differences https://blog.appdynamics.com/database/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-mariadb-percona-forks-of-mysql/

Comment: Thank you George for your answers and the link.

Comment: percona is mostly for galera clusters

Comment: imo faster, more dependable (have production cluster running)